# how to display pop-up contact form without using iframe and using a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

This is my html code

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Modal Popup</title>

    <body>
    <a href="https://dev88.wufoo.com/forms/ze7xusq0j2tum9/" onclick="window.open(this.href,  null, 'height=823, width=680, toolbar=0, location=0, status=1, scrollbars=1, resizable=1'); return false">Please fill out my form.</a>

    </body>
    </html>
```

May i know, how to display this contact us form as pop up and also click outside it should closed.
What my mistake in this code. can you help me?

Comment: The problem is that when you click in the <a> you go to the link instead of the popups open, right?

Comment: No, i need when click the link, it will display pop-up form

Comment: Yes, but in your example, instead of display the popup ... you go to this https://from100.wufoo.com/forms/sfzxgmx02j3w8g/ ?

Comment: Check my answer, but i'm not sure if it helps you.

Comment: I dont understand your question :(

Comment: please see my code above, and help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to satisfy the "click outside it should be closed" requirement, you will need some JS to keep track of when the window is opened and closed. When you open the window from the parent page, it will open a popup, and if you click on the parent page again, while the window is still open, the popup will close.

```
<script>
    var test = document.getElementById('test');
    var win = null;

    test.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        win = window.open(test.href,  null, 'height=823, width=680, toolbar=0, location=0, status=1, scrollbars=1, resizable=1');
        return false;
    });

    window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if(win != null) {
            win.close();
            win = null;
        }
    });
</script>

...

<a href="https://dev88.wufoo.com/forms/ze7xusq0j2tum9/" id="test">Please fill out my form.</a>
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/spryno724/b857X/2/

Comment: may i know what is this <a id="open">Open</a>

Comment: Just a "link" to click on and open the jQuery dialog.

Comment: Based on your description, your existing code won't satisfy your requirements. Do you just want a simple popup and that's it?

Comment: with my code need to add some script, so only it will display as pop-up

Comment: According to my test it looks like your code is bringing up a popup, is that not what you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/spryno724/b857X/

Comment: My code works fine, What i need is, after displayed contact form, when click outside of form, it should be closed.

Comment: did you get my question?

Comment: still didn't understand my problem, when run your code, it display as normal, i neeed as new pop-up..

Comment: that link styas permanantly, and that contact form shows as new pop-up

Comment: Ok, then. You will need to very much clarify your question. I am answering your question as I understand it. I can't keep trying to answer a question that I am not understanding.

Comment: Do you mean a new tab?

Comment: Is [this](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) (button `Launch demo modal`) what you're looking for?

Comment: exactly this " launch demo modal" @Michal Leszczyk, but that site(you mentioned) use by button, but i need use with my code

Comment: @spryno724: in your working fine, but use your in localhost, it didn't work, please help me.

Comment: You can use one of [these jQuery plugin](http://www.sitepoint.com/14-jquery-modal-dialog-boxes/) and [$.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) (as long, as the form you're opening is in the same origin).

Comment: @MichalLeszczyk That's a nice resource for modals. However, the OP is trying to load content from Wufoo.com